# Bootstrap active menu bar color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently making a website using bootstrap. I have a menu bar on top, and I would like to change the color or background color of the specific menu bar when the section of the website is in. Like example, one of menu is call about, and there is a section in homepage call about. When the person is on the about section of the webpage, I want menu "about" will change into different color background.

I used data-spy(scroll) and data-target(my-navbar) to check if it's work, but it was not working. Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

P.S. This is my navbar part and body part that I use it. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Provision Health & Wellness</title>
 <meta name="description" content="ProvisionHW">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>

  <style>
  body {
   padding-top: 40;
  }

  h2 {
   text-align: center;
  }

  </style>
  

 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

  <!-- Navbar -->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Provision Health&Wellness</a>
     </div> <!-- Navbar Header-->

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#health_product">Health Product</a></li>
       <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#slim_product">Slim Product</a></li>
       <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
       <li><a href="#skin_product">Skin Product</a></li>
       <li><a href="#contact_us">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- End Container-->
   </nav> <!-- End navbar-->
```

Comment: You haven't closed your list tags `<li><a href="#health_product">Health Product</a>` and your example works as expected. Post a minimal working example that shows the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried some custom CSS code on your navbar, or on the elements of the navbar?

Comment: I fixed </li> one, but it still doesn't work. I did not custom css code on my navbar. I have updated my code!

Comment: Are you using Wordpress, or any other kind of CSS that may add a different class to the `<body>` depending on which page you're on?

Comment: I am not using Wordpress, I am using bootstrap only. I am making a website from the scratch. I did not make separate css file, but I put style code little bit below the header part. I updated my code above, so it should show style codes.

Comment: Do you have a separate HTML File for each page/section?

Comment: I have all of them in one HTML file. Do you want me to upload the rest of HTML codes?

Comment: No, I should have noticed that from your links. Have you looked at Bootstrap Scrollspy? Isn't this what you want to do? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fiddle that's working.

https://jsfiddle.net/5e1n0nhw/1/

Here is jQuery that tracks active section

```
$(function() {
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(e) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }
    , 1500, 'easeInOutExpo' //add/remove for smooth scroll
    );
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Don't forget to include jQuery easing.

Add id of page-top to your body element and href page-top to your logo so you can scroll to top on click.

Add class page-scroll on all a elements that you want to lead to section.

Wrap all sections in section tag.

And now you can style active link with css

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{
color:green;
}
```

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Comment: so I should change the id of page-top for my actual section part or navigation bar?

Comment: You just add id of page-top or anything else in body tag. Than you add href with same name as id of body in your logo element. But if you don't want to link page top you don't nees to do it. Just look at fiddle I posted. You van copy it and it'll work. Just include easing...

Comment: I add javascript and css into my html code.. but it's not working somehow. but it works well in fiddle.. I don't know why.

Comment: Did you inclided easing? If yes make new fiddle with your exact code else include easing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this awesome tool that can customize your navbar color and give you the css needed.

http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/